# How to partially specialize a template based on the relation between its two integer parameters

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I want to design a m x n matrix class (as a template parameterized by m rows and n columns) and need to specialize it in order to equip it with operations that are mathematically possible based on three conditions:

1. m > n
2. m == n
3. no specialization for m < n, that is, basic or default implementation

The template signature is simply:

```
template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T = double> class MatrixBase
{
....
};
```

How do I do that? Can it be done with type traits? Or should I use `std::conditional<>` or `std::enable_if<>` ?. Conceptually, what I want to accomplish is to **add** methods to a class but without subclassing it and creating any inheritance hierarchy. The derivation tree I want to use for other things, namely the data storage within the matrix.

So I would like to have a matrix that if declared as for instance `MatrixBase<4, 4, float>` has (by virtue of specialization) a method called `inverse ()`, while matrices declared with m <> n don't. Similarly, extra methods for matrices with m > n.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with `std::enable_if`:

```
template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T = double>
class MatrixBase
{
public:

    template <typename T1 = T>
    std::enable_if_t<m == n, MatrixBase<m, m, T1>> inverse() const
    {
        // Calculate inverse
        return{};
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    auto msquare = MatrixBase<4, 4>();
    auto mrect = MatrixBase<4, 3>();
    msquare.inverse(); // No error
    mrect.inverse();   // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

For partial specialization you can also use `enable_if`:

```
template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T = double, typename E = void>
class MatrixBase
{
public:

    template <typename T1 = T>
    std::enable_if_t<m == n, MatrixBase<m, m, T1>> inverse() const
    {
        // Calculate inverse
        return{};
    }
};

template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T>
class MatrixBase<m, n, T, std::enable_if_t<m == n, void>>
{
public:

    static bool m_equals_n()
    {
        return true;
    }

};

template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T>
class MatrixBase<m, n, T, std::enable_if_t<n < m, void>>
{
public:

    static bool m_greater_than_n()
    {
        return true;
    }

};


template <size_t m, size_t n, typename T>
class MatrixBase < m, n, T, std::enable_if_t<m < n, void>>
{
public:

    static bool m_less_than_n()
    {
        return true;
    }

};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    auto msquare = MatrixBase<4, 4>();
    auto m_4_3 = MatrixBase<4, 3>();
    auto m_3_4 = MatrixBase<3, 4>();

    msquare.m_equals_n();
    //msquare.m_greater_than_n();  // Compilation error
    m_4_3.m_greater_than_n();
    m_3_4.m_less_than_n();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would not really compile, I suggest mentioning that its a draft

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov, there's a comment in the code saying that there's a compilation error on that line.

Comment: thats not the only compilation problem there

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov, Thank you! I have updated my code. It's funny, but my first version compiled without problems in Visual C++ 2015. I posted my answer after I had tried to compile it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question however, since this is not a specialization. So forget about matrix inversion and let me rephrase the question like this: how to specialize a template class A<m, n, T> based on the relationship between m and n? Is it, first of all, possible? Or a simpler case: template <int m> class A. How to specialize it for m >0 (or m<0).

Comment: Thanks a lot Max, I think that solves my problem. In essence a method has to be BOTH a template and use std::enable_if. I tried both before but never together.